# How to type currentTarget on addEventListener

Tags: typescript

I use this code

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const { className, id, src = null, href = null } = event.currentTarget as HTMLElement;

    console.log(className, id, src, href);
});
```

Here, `currentTarget` can be anything, a div, button, anchor etc. I can't assign `currentTarget` as `HTMLElement` because some properties are missing in the type def (href and src)

As a workaround I'm currently extending `HTMLElement` like this

```js
interface CustomHTMLElement extends HTMLElement {
    target?: string;
    href?: string;
    src?: string;
}
```

Is my workaround the best solution or should I use an enum type (HTMLDivElement | HTMLButtonElement | HTMLAnchorElement | ...)? Or something else?

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-xi64s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your event can literally be anything, you can't do anything here.

You have to check `currentTarget` with `instanceof` when accessing specific properties.

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.currentTarget instanceof Element) {
        const { className, id } = event.currentTarget;
        const src = (event.currentTarget instanceof HTMLImageElement && event.currentTarget.src) || null;
        const href = (event.currentTarget instanceof HTMLAnchorElement && event.currentTarget.href) || null;

      console.log(className, id, src, href);
    }
});
```

However, here, `href` and `src` can be null because they may don't exist on other elements.

Answer (score 3):

If your `currentTarget` can be anything and if you do not need to access to any property, make it `any`.

If you need to do some actions for some types, you can do it like this:

```js
if (event.currentTarget instanceof HTMLAnchorElement) {
  // You can use: event.currentTarget.href
}
```